# Why background-image works in one place but in another doesn't?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm working on some custom wordpress theme and in my style.css I've got two places where I'm using background-image, here it works fine:

```
 #gallery {
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-image: url("img/gallery.jpg");
min-height: 100vh;
padding-top: 50px;
color: white;
text-align: center;
}
```

but here it doesn't show :

```
#pageHeader {
background-image: url("img/pageHeader.jpg");
overflow: auto;
overflow-y: hidden;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 30px;
padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Second is for the page.php file, and other functions such as text-align works fine, only issue is with background-image. Of course both jpgs are in the same location.

I've checked and it gives "Could not load the image"

Comment: Is it being overridden by another style? Have you used your browser's inspector to see? Hit F12.

Comment: try using an url like `url("../img/pageHeader.jpg")` . and/or recheck the name of the image and it's location.

Comment: doesn't work, firefox inspector says "could not load the image", but its loading in brackets

Answer (score 0):

From your description several possible problems can be. For instance, it is possible that the rule was not applied at all, since `#pageHeader` does not exist (for whatever reasons, including, but not limited to typos). Or it is possible that the rule is applied to `#pageHeader`, but another rule overrides `background-image`. Also, it is possible that it is inside an `iframe` from where the relative location to the picture is different (if the page inside the `iframe` is not inside the same folder as your main page and not in a sibling folder either). Also, your rule which is not applied might be unavailable due to browser cache (clear browser cache), or server caching systems, like CloudFlare.

The solution is to right-click on the HTML tag, click on Inspect and see what CSS rules are applied. If this rule is applied, then at least you know that you are using the right version of your CSS and can take a look at where the image is being loaded from. When you reach to this point, the solution should be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the solution is - I was using lampp on ubuntu, and in some way it didn't work, but moving back to windows xampp solve this problem. It may be something with permissions.